# Button appears disabled until i click out of input in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a form (heat index calculator) which take 2 inputs, dropdown and button, button is disabled if there is nothing in the inputs or if the inputs are invalid, everything works fine except when i type in both inputs valid arguments the button still appears disabled until i click out of the input. Is there way to enable the button as soon as i type valid argument in the input without having to click out of it to show ? and another similar issue is.. i have dropdown there with celsius and fahrenheit options, when selected F the minimum value user have to type is 80 and for C minimum is 26 and the issue is when i choose C for eg and type 50 and change my mind and select fahrenheit instead,  the validation error doesnt show up.. i have to delete the value and if i type again the 50 now the error shows

this is html

```
<form [formGroup]="heatIndexForm" class="wrapper" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <label class="temperature-row">
      <p class="temperature-input">Air Temperature</p>
      <div class="field col-12 md:col-4">
        <p-inputNumber
        [style]="{'height': '51px'}"
        formControlName="temperature"
        mode="decimal"
        class="form-control">
      </p-inputNumber>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="temperatureValidationFahrenheit">Temperature must be 80&deg;F or higher!</div>
      <div class="validation-error" *ngIf="temperatureValidationCelsius" >Temperature must be 26&deg;C or higher!</div>
    </div>
      <p-dropdown
      class="form-control"
      [style]="{'height':'51px', 'paddingTop': '5px', 'marginLeft': '5px'}"
      formControlName="selectedTemp"
      (onChange)="selectionChanged()" [options]="temps"
      optionLabel="units"></p-dropdown>
    </label>
    <label class="humidity-row">
      <p class="humidity-input">Relative Humidity</p>
      <div [style]="{'position': 'relative'}" class="field col-12 md:col-4">
        <p-inputNumber   [style]="{'height': '51px'}" mode="decimal"formControlName="humidity" class="form-control"></p-inputNumber>
        <div class="percent">%</div>
        <div  class="validation-error" *ngIf="heatIndexForm.controls['humidity'].invalid">Humidity must be 0% - 100%</div>
      </div>
    </label>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button
      class="form-control"
      [disabled]="disableCalculateButton"
       pButton
       label="Calculate"></button>
      <p-button label="Reset" (onClick)="reset()"></p-button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

form ts

```
export class HeatIndexComponent implements OnInit {
  haveResult: boolean = false;
  temps: Temperature[];
  heatIndexForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private heatIndexService: HeatIndexService,
    private localStore: LocalService
  ) {
    this.temps = [
      new Temperature('Celsius', 'C'),
      new Temperature('Fahreheit', 'F'),
    ];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heatIndexForm = new FormGroup({
      temperature: new FormControl(null, Validators.min(26)),
      humidity: new FormControl(null, [Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0)]),
      selectedTemp: new FormControl(new Temperature('Celsius', 'C')),
      result: new FormControl(''),
      resultComment: new FormControl(''),
    });
  }

  get temperatureValidationFahrenheit() {
    return (
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['selectedTemp'].value.code === 'F' &&
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].invalid
    );
  }

  get temperatureValidationCelsius() {
    return (
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['selectedTemp'].value.code === 'C' &&
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].invalid
    );
  }

  get disableCalculateButton() {
    return (
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].invalid ||
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['humidity'].invalid ||
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].value == null ||
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['humidity'].value == null
    );
  }

  selectionChanged() {
    this.haveResult = false;
    const value = this.heatIndexForm.get('selectedTemp').value;
    this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].clearValidators();
    if (value.code !== 'C') {
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].setValidators(
        Validators.min(80)
      );
    }
    if (value.code === 'C') {
      this.heatIndexForm.controls['temperature'].setValidators(
        Validators.min(26)
      );
    }
    this.heatIndexForm.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

i tried the button issue with template driven approach but same thing happened

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example. This code has lots of customized components. I wasnt able to reproduce the issue with changing dropdown value but I'd be happy to help with that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enable and disable submit button as soon as you type, let angular validate the form for you instead of providing your own validator method `disableCalculateButton()`. Add `Validators.required` to `temperature` and `humidity` fields (instead of manually checking if they're null):

**component.ts**

```js
temperature: new FormControl(null, [Validators.min(26), Validators.required]),
humidity: new FormControl(null, [Validators.max(100), Validators.min(0), Validators.required]),
```

And change `[disabled]` value in submit button. to only display error message when field is populated, check if the form field has been `touched`

**component.html**

```html
<div class="validation-error" *ngIf="temperatureValidationFahrenheit && 
heatIndexForm.controls.temperature.touched">
          Temperature must be 80&deg;F or higher!
</div>
<div class="validation-error" *ngIf="temperatureValidationCelsius && 
heatIndexForm.controls.temperature.touched">
          Temperature must be 26&deg;C or higher!
</div>
.
.
.
<div
class="validation-error"
*ngIf="heatIndexForm.controls['humidity'].invalid &&
 heatIndexForm.controls.humidity.touched">
          Humidity must be 0% - 100%
</div>
.
.
.
<button
    class="form-control"
    [disabled]="heatIndexForm.invalid"
    pButton
    label="Calculate">
submit
</button>
```

Link to [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5hdwcd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2FTemperature.model.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)

For your second issue unfortunatly I couldn't find any solution but I think defining a [custom validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators) would help alot. Manging multiple error messages for one field with `*ngIf` is a bit of trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your help, i tried your solution but it didnt gave me the desired functionality, now the validation error is shown all the time and the button issue is still there. I created stackblitz here u can check(not sure why the input looks like that there but if u click on it and click on your keyboard either F or C its gonna change so u can see the 2nd issue): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-pjaojr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2FTemperature.model.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: *i meant the error is showing even if inputs are empty not all the time

Comment: But the issue is still there ? I mean when u fill in temperature field then fill humidity field u have to click somewhere for the button to appear enabled

Comment: Ok so after lots of trial and error out of despair I decided to replace all the `p-inputNumber` tags with `input` tags and it works! Now button is activated as soon as all the fields are valid. So I think the issue lies in that component. [updated code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yuijkg?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Yes! That was it, i dont think that would come to my mind haha .. thanks a lot for your  help .. works great now